# How to synchronize uploaded files on Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, backend

Probably a stupid question, but I am new to Azure and it seems there is a lot of documentation on the topic, which is intimidating in the beginning.

I have a small website where users can upload files and then some content will be displayed in the webpage. My question is, if the site is hosted in Azure, on multiple machines, how can I synchronize these files across machines? Or, how can I do this without having duplicates?

How is this normally done? I can't be the first with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended approach is to use **`blob storage`** for storing user generated content. If you search here, you will find plenty examples regarding the benefits of using blob storage. One of the biggest benefit is that you're not constrained by the size. Each storage account today can store 500 TB of data whereas if you store the files locally in your Web App, there's a limit on the disk size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed this look like the approach I would like. Do you know how can I use this with MVC?

Comment: Basically Azure Storage has a .Net SDK (Client Library). You would need to use that in your MVC application. You may find this guide useful: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/. Also see this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/490178/How-to-Use-Azure-Blob-Storage-with-Azure-Web-Sites (Though it is quite old so use this for general guidance only regarding Azure Websites/Blob Storage integration). HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting on multiple machines is totally transparent for developers.

Work with it like you will do on unique machine

Comment: Yes, but I'm not talking about deployment. A user uploads a file to a machine (for example a profile picture), another user which connects to different azure machine will not see the image until is synchronized.